# How to Sort using JHtml::('grid.sort) and join query?

Tags: mysql, join, joomla

i am trying to sort table data using column name in joomla administrator. but when i tried to sort table using column in join table, it gives error as follows

```
500 - An error has occurred.

Champ 'a.product_name' inconnu dans order clause SQL=SELECT a.*,created_by.name AS created_by FROM `jos_alphabatic_formdata` AS a LEFT JOIN jos_users AS created_by ON created_by.id = a.created_by ORDER BY a.product_name asc Champ 'a.product_name' inconnu dans order clause SQL=SELECT a.*,created_by.name AS created_by FROM `jos_alphabatic_formdata` AS a LEFT JOIN jos_users AS created_by ON created_by.id = a.created_by ORDER BY a.product_name asc LIMIT 0, 20 Champ 'a.product_name' inconnu dans order clause SQL=SELECT a.*,created_by.name AS created_by FROM `jos_alphabatic_formdata` AS a LEFT JOIN jos_users AS created_by ON created_by.id = a.created_by ORDER BY a.product_name asc
```

this is my file where table is generated:

```
<table class="adminlist">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="1%">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkall-toggle" value="" onclick="checkAll(this)" />
            </th>

            <th class='left'>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_ALPHABATIC_FORMDATAS_ORDER_ID', 'a.order_id', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
            </th>
            <th class='left'>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_ALPHABATIC_FORMDATAS_CATEGORY_ID', 'a.category_id', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
            </th>
            <th class='left'>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'Product Name', 'a.product_name', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
            <?php //echo "Product Name"; ?>
            </th>
            <th class='left'>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'Created On', 'a.created_on', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>

            <?php// echo "Created On"; ?>
            </th>
            <th class='left'>
             <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'Order Status', 'a.order_status', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>

            <?php //echo "Order Status"; ?>
            </th>
            <th>
             <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'Email', 'a.email', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>

            <?php // echo "Email"  ?>
            </th>

            <th class='left'>
             <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'Item Price', 'a.item_price', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>

            <?php //echo "Item Price"; ?>
            </th>
            <th class='left'>
             <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'Saved', 'a.saved', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>

            <?php //echo "Saved"; ?>
            </th>
            <th class='left'>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'Validated', 'a.validated', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>

            <?php //echo "Validated"; ?>
            </th>
            <th class='left'>
             <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'Last Modified', 'a.last_modified', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>

            <?php //echo "Last Modified"; ?>
            </th>

        <!--    <th class='left'>
            <?php //echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_ALPHABATIC_FORMDATAS_DATA', 'a.data', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
            </th> -->
            <th class='left'>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'COM_ALPHABATIC_FORMDATAS_CREATED_BY', 'a.created_by', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
            </th>


            <?php if (isset($this->items[0]->state)) { ?>
            <th width="5%">
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'JPUBLISHED', 'a.state', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
            </th>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if (isset($this->items[0]->ordering)) { ?>
            <th width="10%">
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'JGRID_HEADING_ORDERING', 'a.ordering', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
                <?php if ($canOrder && $saveOrder) :?>
                    <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.order',  $this->items, 'filesave.png', 'formdatas.saveorder'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </th>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if (isset($this->items[0]->id)) { ?>
            <th width="1%" class="nowrap">
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.sort',  'JGRID_HEADING_ID', 'a.id', $listDirn, $listOrder); ?>
            </th>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <?php 
            if(isset($this->items[0])){
                $colspan = count(get_object_vars($this->items[0]));
            }
            else{
                $colspan = 10;
            }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="<?php echo $colspan ?>">
                <?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>

    <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) :
        $ordering   = ($listOrder == 'a.ordering');
        $canCreate  = $user->authorise('core.create',       'com_alphabatic');
        $canEdit    = $user->authorise('core.edit',         'com_alphabatic');
        $canCheckin = $user->authorise('core.manage',       'com_alphabatic');
        $canChange  = $user->authorise('core.edit.state',   'com_alphabatic');


        ?>
        <tr class="row<?php echo $i % 2; ?>">
            <td class="center">
                <?php echo JHtml::_('grid.id', $i, $item->id); ?>
            </td>

            <td>
                <?php echo $item->order_id; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $item->category_id; ?>
            </td>
            <?php $this->getproductdata($item->order_id);  ?>

            <td>
            <?php  echo $this->item_name; ?>
            </td>

            <td>
            <?php echo $this->created_on; ?>
            </td>

            <td>
            <?php echo $this->order_status; ?>
            </td>

            <td>
            <?php echo $this->get_email; ?>
            </td>

            <td>
             <?php echo $this->product_price; ?>
            </td>

            <?php
            $data_1 = json_decode($item->data);
            $data_2 = (array) $data_1;
            $c1 = array();
             foreach($data_2 as $key1 => $value1)
             {
               $c1[] = $value1->status;
             }
             $c2 = implode(',',$c1);
             $saved_count = substr_count($c2, 's');
             $validated_count = substr_count($c2,'v');
             ?>

             <td>
             <?php echo $saved_count; ?>
            </td>

            <td>
             <?php echo $validated_count; ?>
            </td>

             <td>
             <?php echo $this->get_modified; ?>
            </td>








    <!--    <td>
                <?php //echo $item->data; ?>
            </td>  -->
            <td>
                <?php echo $item->created_by; ?>
            </td>


            <?php if (isset($this->items[0]->state)) { ?>
                <td class="center">
                    <?php echo JHtml::_('jgrid.published', $item->state, $i, 'formdatas.', $canChange, 'cb'); ?>
                </td>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if (isset($this->items[0]->ordering)) { ?>
                <td class="order">
                    <?php if ($canChange) : ?>
                        <?php if ($saveOrder) :?>
                            <?php if ($listDirn == 'asc') : ?>
                                <span><?php echo $this->pagination->orderUpIcon($i, true, 'formdatas.orderup', 'JLIB_HTML_MOVE_UP', $ordering); ?></span>
                                <span><?php echo $this->pagination->orderDownIcon($i, $this->pagination->total, true, 'formdatas.orderdown', 'JLIB_HTML_MOVE_DOWN', $ordering); ?></span>
                            <?php elseif ($listDirn == 'desc') : ?>
                                <span><?php echo $this->pagination->orderUpIcon($i, true, 'formdatas.orderdown', 'JLIB_HTML_MOVE_UP', $ordering); ?></span>
                                <span><?php echo $this->pagination->orderDownIcon($i, $this->pagination->total, true, 'formdatas.orderup', 'JLIB_HTML_MOVE_DOWN', $ordering); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php $disabled = $saveOrder ?  '' : 'disabled="disabled"'; ?>
                        <input type="text" name="order[]" size="5" value="<?php echo $item->ordering;?>" <?php echo $disabled ?> class="text-area-order" />
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php echo $item->ordering; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if (isset($this->items[0]->id)) { ?>
            <td class="center">
                <?php echo (int) $item->id; ?>
            </td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this function is called when i tried to click on product_name column. it works when i tried to sort using columns from alphabetic form data table as below

```
protected function getListQuery() {
    // Create a new query object.
    $db = $this->getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Select the required fields from the table.
    $query->select(
            $this->getState(
                    'list.select', 'a.*'
            )
    );
    $query->from('`#__alphabatic_formdata` AS a');


    // Join over the user field 'created_by'
    $query->select('created_by.name AS created_by');
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__users AS created_by ON created_by.id = a.created_by');



    // Filter by search in title
    $search = $this->getState('filter.search');
    if (!empty($search)) {
        if (stripos($search, 'id:') === 0) {
            $query->where('a.id = ' . (int) substr($search, 3));
        } else {
            $search = $db->Quote('%' . $db->escape($search, true) . '%');

        }
    }




    // Add the list ordering clause.
    $orderCol = $this->state->get('list.ordering');
    $orderDirn = $this->state->get('list.direction');
    if ($orderCol && $orderDirn) {
        $query->order($db->escape($orderCol . ' ' . $orderDirn));
    }

    return $query;
}
```

can any one help me solve this issue ? how to sort using columns from join part of query?

[image]

Comment: no joomla master ???

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).